# Splitting a string of values like 1030:0,1031:1,1032:2 and storing data in database

Tags: php

I have a bunch of photos on a page and using jQuery UI's Sortable plugin, to allow for them to be reordered.

When my sortable function fires, it writes a new order sequence:

```
1030:0,1031:1,1032:2,1040:3,1033:4
```

Each item of the comma delimited string, consists of the photo ID and the order position, separated by a colon. When the user has *completely* finished their reordering, I'm posting this order sequence to a PHP page via AJAX, to store the changes in the database. Here's where I get into trouble.

I have no problem getting my script to work, but I'm pretty sure it's the incorrect way to achieve what I want, and will suffer hugely in performance and resources - I'm hoping somebody could advise me as to what would be the best approach.

This is my PHP script that deals with the sequence:

```
if ($sorted_order) {
    $exploded_order = explode(',',$sorted_order);
    foreach ($exploded_order as $order_part) {
        $exploded_part = explode(':',$order_part);
        $part_count = 0;
        foreach ($exploded_part as $part) {
            $part_count++;
            if ($part_count == 1) {
                $photo_id = $part;
            } elseif ($part_count == 2) {
                $order = $part;
            }
            $SQL = "UPDATE article_photos ";
            $SQL .= "SET order_pos = :order_pos ";
            $SQL .= "WHERE photo_id = :photo_id;";
            ... rest of PDO stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

My concerns arise from the nested `foreach` functions and also running so many database updates. If a given sequence contained 150 items, would this script cry for help? If it will, how could I improve it?

** This is for an admin page, so it won't be heavily abused **

Comment: you could do one insert\update query rather than put it inside the loop - far more efficient

Comment: First, use a profiler to see if that's really a bottleneck (if you are doing 150 database inserts afterwards, probably not). Else consider `preg_match_all('/(\d+):(\d+)/')` and `array_combine`.

Comment: @Dagon I'm pretty sure I cannot have one UPDATE query. Each photo has its own row and has a field called `order_pos`. If you can prove me wrong, I'd be very grateful to know how. Maybe you could supply an answer suggesting how.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, added an answer with an approach i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use one update, with some cleaver code like so:

create the array $data['order'] in the loop then:

```
$q = "UPDATE article_photos SET order_pos = (CASE photo_id ";
    foreach($data['order'] as $sort => $id){
        $q .= " WHEN {$id} THEN {$sort}";
    }
    $q .= " END ) WHERE photo_id IN (".implode(",",$data['order']).")";
```

a little clearer perhaps

```
UPDATE article_photos SET order_pos = (CASE photo_id
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 999
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 1000
    WHEN id = 3 THEN 1001
    END)
WHERE photo_id IN (1,2,3)
```

i use this approach for exactly what your doing, updating sort orders

Comment: I chose this answer because of the help in reducing the SQL update queries. It also inspired me to send an array of the photo_ids/orders instead of a delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making your script even simplier and changing names of the variables, so the code would be way more readable.

```
$parts = explode(',',$sorted_order);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    list($id, $position) = explode(':',$order_part);
    //Now you can work with $id and $position ;
}
```

More info about `list`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

**Also, about performance and your data structure:**

The way you store your data is not perfect. But that way you will not suffer any performance issues, that way you need to send less data, less overhead overall.

However the drawback of your data structure is that most probably you will be unable to establish relationships between tables and make joins or alter table structure in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the second foreach: you know it's going to be two parts if your data passes validation (I'm assuming you validated this. If not: you should =) so just do:

```
if (count($exploded_part) == 2) {
  $id = $exploded_part[0];
  $seq = $exploded_part[1];
  /* rest of code */
} else {
  /* error - data does not conform despite validation */
}
```

As for update hammering: do your DB updates in a transaction. Your db will queue the ops, but not commit them to the main DB until you commit the transaction, at which point it'll happily do the update "for real" at lightning speed.